# ¿Cómo puedo leer dos ficheros a la vez en paralelo en Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Quiero coger elementos de dos listas diferentes, convertirlos a variables y operar un comando recursivamente.

```
#!/bin/bash 

cat A.txt | cut -c-17 A.txt | sed '1,2d' > B.txt 
cut -c 20,21 A.txt | sed '1,3d' > C.txt
rm A.txt

while IFS= read -r b ; do echo "$b"; done < B.txt
while IFS= read -r c ; do echo "$c"; done < C.txt
```

El problema es que me gustaría que el bucle ( `while IFS= read -r...`), operara sobre dos variables llamando a dos textos diferentes. La pregunta es si existe algo parecido a esto:

```
while IFS= read -r b, c ; do command $b * $c; done < B.txt, C.txt`
```

Es resumidas cuentas, ¿hay alguna manera de operar `IFS= read -r` sobre dos textos, almacenar esas variables y operar linea a linea con ellas [Línea 1 de A.txt interactúa con Línea 1 de B.txt, Línea 2 (...) Línea 2, etc]?

Espero haber sido claro. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es leer dos ficheros al mismo tiempo, leyendo cada vez la misma línea de cada uno. Es decir, quieres procesar la línea 1 del fichero 1 a la vez que la línea 2 del fichero 2 y así sucesivamente.

Para ello, solamente debes utilizar un descriptor de fichero "extra", por ejemplo el 3, y leerlos normalmente y en paralelo:

```
while IFS= read -r datos1 && read -r datos2 <&3
do
   echo "fichero1 -> $datos1"
   echo "fichero2 -> $datos2"
done < fichero1 3< fichero2
```

Veamos un ejemplo muy tonto, en el que en lugar de ficheros le paso una secuencia de número a través de una sustitución de procesos:

```
while read -r a && read -r b <&3
do
    echo "$a - $b"
done < <(seq 5) 3< <(seq 6 10)
```

Que nos devuelve:

```
1 - 6
2 - 7
3 - 8
4 - 9
5 - 10
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! He resuelto el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Con **exec** puedas ejecutar todo el texto en una variable, de esta forma no necesitas dos variables. Guarda todo en un mismo archivo, e.g a_and_b.txt:

```
echo 1+1.1 | bc
echo 2+2.2 | bc
echo 3+3.3 | bc
```

Luego:

```
while IFS= read -r b; do exec $b; done < ~/tmp/a_and_b.txt
```

Debe dar:

```
$ while IFS= read -r b; do eval $b; done < ~/tmp/a_and_b.txt
2.1
4.2
6.3
```

Que sólo necesita una variable, en vez de 3.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, el problema es que la función de destino no es una operación aritmética. Sería algo así 'while echo Mi nombre es "$b" y vivo en "&c"; done

Comment: No necesita ser una función aritmética. Es sólo un ejemplo. **exec** en bash ejecuta cualquier cosa que sea ejecutable en bash.  Lo que debes evitar es componer el comando `echo Mi nombre es "$b" y vivo en "&c"` directamente en el while. Debes hacerlo en otro archivo de texto.

Comment: Mmm, entonces no entiendo la solución. Muchas gracias de todas formas. Voy a investigar exec.